# How to apply a style from a resource dictionary if the Tag property is set

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

I have a style in a resource dictionary as so

```
<Style x:Key="heading" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26" />
</Style>
```

and I wish to have it assigned to control if some trigger
condition is met. For example

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Style.Triggers>

        <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="header" >
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26" />
        </Trigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

works fine

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Style.Triggers>

        <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="header" >
            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource heading}" />
        </Trigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

gives an error that a Style trigger cannot change the Style property of the
associated target which sort of makes sense but is there a work around 
for this?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to put the triggers into the resource dictionary not the Style like so

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="headerTrigger"/>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and define the trigger in a resource dictionary like so

```
<Trigger x:Key="headerTrigger" Property="Label.Tag" Value="header" >
    <Setter Property="Label.FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="Label.BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="Label.BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
</Trigger>
```